# When moving an item from one listbox to another, how do I add to the string going into the second listbox?

Tags: c#, tostring

Ok, so my application is a simple baby gift registry. In the left groupBox, I have 2 input text boxes(item, store) and a listBox(lstWish) for output. This side is the Wish List. In the right groupBox, I have 2 input text boxes(firstName, lastName) and a listBox(lstPurchased) for output. Upon a button_click, the selected item from lstWish is moved to lstPurchased. lstWish currently outputs like "Item available at Store".

When the item goes from lstWish to lstPurchased I want to add "from firstName lastName".  So the lstPurchased will read "Item available at Store from firstName lastName". How do I add the second half of the string while moving it over?

Here is the method that moves the item over:

```
private void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox lstWish, ListBox lstPurchased)
    {
        ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = lstWish.SelectedItems;
        foreach (var item in sourceItems)
        {
            lstPurchased.Items.Add(item);
        }
        while (lstWish.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            lstWish.Items.Remove(lstWish.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
    }
```

And here is the code for the button click:

```
private void btnBuy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFirst.Text == "" || txtLast.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter first and last name.", "Warning");
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Click Yes to confirm purchase. Click No to cancel."
                , "Thank You", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (lstWish.SelectedIndex >=0)
            {
                MoveListBoxItems(lstWish, lstPurchased);                   
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

The list is a collection is a List. There are two custom classes, Gift and Guest.  Here is the class Gift that has the toString that populates the listBox:

```
namespace GiftRegistry
{
class Gift
{
    #region Fields
    private string _item;
    private string _store;
    //private string _purchaser;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string Item { get; set; }//modify the set clauses to include regex and title case and          .trim()

    public string Store { get; set; }

    //public string Purchaser { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public Gift()
    {
        this.Item = String.Empty;
        this.Store = String.Empty;
    }

    public Gift(string Item, string Store)
    {
        this.Item = Item;
        this.Store = Store;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Method
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} availble at {1}", this.Item, this.Store);
    }
    #endregion        
}
```

}

Guest class:

```
class Guest
{
    #region Fields
    private string _lastName;
    private string _firstName;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {                
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Name", "Please enter a name");
            _lastName = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    public string FirstName 
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {//see above about regular expressions
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Name", "Please enter a name");
            _firstName = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public Guest()
    {
        this.LastName = String.Empty;
        this.FirstName = String.Empty;
    }

    public Guest(string lastName)
    {
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.FirstName = String.Empty;
    }

    public Guest(string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.FirstName = firstName;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Method
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName);
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: A string is a string.  How do you usually join two strings?  `str1 + str2`.  That's it, that's all.  The first string is `item` so just concatenate the second string and then add the result.  You're trying to take something simple and make it hard.

Comment: I've done it with a string.join in another app, but I can't get that to work here. Would I write an override method in my main form, or would that be driven from the Guest class?

Comment: Like I said, you're trying to make this hard when it's one of the simplest things you could ever do.  You wouldn't use `String.Join` because that's for joining a list of values with a separator between them.  That's not what you want to do.  You simply want to join two strings so just use a `+` operator.  You add the item here: `lstPurchased.Items.Add(item);`.  Simply change that to: `lstPurchased.Items.Add(item + str2);`.  `item` needs to be a string and how you get the second string is up to you but it's that simple.

Comment: The `ListBox` will display whatever you give it.  If you are only seeing the contents of `item` then that means that what you concatenated it with contains no visible characters, i.e. `this.txtFirst` and `this.txtLast` must have contained no visible characters when you executed that code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I got it to work! I wish this stuff was "simple" for me, but it is not.  I am just trying to pass a programming class to graduate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MoveListBoxItems()`, you can concatenate the firstName and lastName with:

```
lstPurchased.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} from {1} {2}", item.ToString(), firstName, lastName));
```

Comment: Wouldn't that put that whole string in my first listBox(lstWish)?

Comment: I got the suggestion in the comments of my OP to work, but in the interest of education I'd like to know more about your idea. How do I get my form code to recognize the firstName, lastName from my Guest class? I got it to work like this: lstPurchased.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} from {1} {2}", item.ToString(), txtFirst.Text, txtLast.Text));

Comment: @ScottT, if you could post the source code for your Guest class, I would gladly have a look at it.

Comment: Guest class is at the end of the OP. Thanks

Comment: The OP doesn't show when or how the Guest class gets instantiated so I'll assume it does and the FirstName and LastName have been set. Then instead of referencing the textboxes, your solution would call the ToString() method: lstPurchased.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} from {1}", item.ToString(), guestObj.ToString()));